# How to get strings from enum

Tags: swift

I am trying to organize a bunch of string parameters in a enum. That way I can exclude the possibility of typos.

```
enum CompassPoint: String {
case n = "North"
case s = "South"
case e = "East"
case w = "West"
}
```

If I do it like this I need to use `.rawValue` to access the string. That is pretty ugly.

If I do it like this:

```
enum CompassPointAlt: String {
case n
case s
case e
case w

  var str: String {
    switch self {
    case .n: return "North"
    case .s: return "South"
    case .e: return "East"
    case .w: return "West"
    }
  }
}
```

I have to use the `.str` property to get the value. Which is visually more explicit, but the declaration is cumbersome.

There has to be a better way. Does anyone have a tipp for me? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use static in combination with enum if you are mostly interested in using the enum for constants

```
enum CompassPoint {
    static let n = "Nort"
    static let s = "South"
    static let e = "East"
    static let w = "West"
}
```

Comment: With this solution, wouldn't it be just as effective (or maybe even better) to use a `struct`?

Comment: You can create many instances from a struct but not from an enum so you will never have more than one instance of your constants.

Answer (score 2):

You could pull off some variation of the following:

```swift
import Foundation

enum Test: String, CustomStringConvertible {
    case n = "North"
    case s = "South"
    case e = "East"
    case w = "West"

    var description: String {
        return self.rawValue
    }
}

print("Enum: \(Test.n)") // Prints: Enum: North
```

`CustomStringConvertible` lets you run the code in the `description` variable without explicitly referencing it when you want to convert to a string. If you dont need the enums to have custom associated values like `Hi` and `Bye` above and you are cool with having the name of the type be what prints, then you can get as small as this:

```swift
import Foundation

enum TestSmall {
     case North
     case South
}

print("Enum: \(TestSmall.North)") // prints: Enum: North
```